# Re-size a div style respect to browser window width and height - Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to change browser width and height into `.test` div. whenever I re-size the browser the current value should change.

```js
$(document).ready(
  function() { 

    window.onresize = function(event) {
      resizeDiv();
    }

    function resizeDiv() {
      var vpw=window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth || document.body.clientWidth;
      var vph=window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight ||document.body.clientHeight;
      $(‘.test’).css({‘height': vph + ‘px’});
    }
               
);
```

```css
.test
{
  background: green;
  padding: 20px;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="test"></div>
```

Comment: You'd be better of with `$(‘.test’).height(vph);`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Example

[example](http://jsfiddle.net/82ag3m4c/)

js

```
function resize() {
    $(".test").css({
    width:  $(window).width(),
    height: $(window).height()
});
}
 resize();
$(window).resize(function(){
 resize();
});
```

if you want minus some pixels

```
function resize() {
    $(".test").css({
        width:  $(window).width() - 15,
        height: $(window).height() - 15
    });
 }
```

Comment: Working well. I have some more doubt?

Comment: Nothing wrong. I want minus some px from this width and height. how can i achieve this.

Comment: Thanks for your time. and how can i get some div's height and width on re-size?

Comment: select the div width class /var width = $(".bllock").width();/ and put it on resize function and after that you can get thw width

Comment: I need one more help Aram.

Answer (score 1):

Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

You use ‘ and ’. In order that your script to run you need to use ' or ".

Comment: Yes, $(‘.test’).css({‘height': vph + ‘px’}); ==> $(‘.test’).css({‘height', vph + ‘px’});

Answer (score 0):

Best practice for what you are asking is to use responsive design: http://responsivedesign.is/examples/playgrounds-and-sandboxes/lots-of-donuts

for example:

```
@media only screen and (min-width: 1300px) { #divId {width:1000px;}}

@media screen and (max-width: 860px) {#divId {width:800px;} }

@media screen and (max-width: 650px) { #divId {width:600px;}}

@media screen and (max-width: 480px) { #divId {width:400px;}}
```

Comment: I dont want css solution. because am doing some what different use.